# Why am I getting a TypeError when trying to call a function in an iFrame from the parent page?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, iframe

I have a page (parent) with an iFrame (child) embedded in it, the iFrame contains a javascript function that I need to call from the parent. The page are on different domains, I don't know if that's the issue though. This is my code on the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveChanges() {
        var iFrame = document.getElementById("iframeSite");
        iFrame.contentWindow.ExecuteSave();
    }
</script>
```

...and my code on the child page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ExecuteSave() {
        alert("test1");
    }
</script>
```

When I call "SaveChanges" in the parent it errors at the line where it attempts to call "ExecuteSave".

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'ExecuteSave' of object [object DOMWindow] 
is not a function
```

I've tried pretty much every variation of calling a child iFrame's function but still receive the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the iframes are in different domains, you won't be able to directly call between them.  This would be a violation of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

There *is* a sanctioned way for having an iframe and a parent communicate.  It's called [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've been using the postMessage for iframe child to parent communication, is it possible then to use it for parent to child communication then?